# Unable to perform if equal by using a jq output

Tags: bash, if-statement, jq

I have an issue with my condition if by using a jq output.

So,

I have a curl to find es snapshot

```
$get_snap=$(curl -s "https://opens.endpoint.com/_snapshot" | jq -e '[.[].settings.bucket][1]')
```

And output :

```
echo $get_snap 
"staging-opens-snap"
```

So, I want to perform a condition to check if $get_snap is equal to "staging-opens-snap" :

```
if [ "$get_snap" = "staging-opens-snap" ]; then
    echo "is same"
else 
    echo "is different"
fi
is different
```

And I always have the result `is different`, anyway.

I tried by using `|tostring` and other stuff, but same result. My if doesn't works.

I don't understand what I miss to be done.

Thanks for your lights :)

Comment: Use `-r` in your jq command to remove the quotes around the output (`--raw-output`)

Comment: Your variable's value contains quotes. You must compare to `'"staging-opens-snap"'` (or use `-r` as suggested already). It might also be worthwhile to perform the comparison with `jq` directly

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the comparison in `jq` itself.

```
if curl ... | jq -e '[.[].settings.bucket][1] == "staging-opens-snap"'; then
    echo "is same"
else
    echo "is different"
fi
```

(I'm assuming the strings are for the example, but if not, you can have `jq` generate them as well without having to care about the exit status:

```
result=$(curl ... | 
          jq -r 'if [.[].settings.bucket][1] == "staging-opens-snap" 
                 then "is same"
                 else "is different"
                 end')
```